# How to convert the following Map foreach code to java 1.6 compatibility?

Tags: java

How do I convert the following code to a Java version 1.6?

```
fruitMap.forEach((fruit, FruitsList) -> {
         Iterator<Fruits> iterator = FruitsList
               .iterator();
         });
```

Comment: What is `fruitMap`, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way:

```
for(Map.Entry<?, List<Fruits>> entry : fruitMap.entrySet()) {
   Iterator<Fruits> iterator = entry.getValue().iterator();
}
```

Comment: WHat happened to the fruitsList?

Comment: `fruitsList` is available as  `entry.getValue()`.

Comment: @Rolando Did you mean this: ① `List<Fruits> list = entry.getValue();` ② `Iterator<Fruits> iterator = list.iterator();` ? ☺

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the iterator of each value;

```
for(FruitsList list : fruitMap.values()) {
   Iterator<Fruits> iterator = list.iterator();
   //do something with the iterator
}
```